# Optimize LINQ to Objects query

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have around 200K records in a list and I'm looping through them and forming another collection. This works fine on my local 64 bit Win 7 but when I move it to a Windows Server 2008 R2, it takes a lot of time. There is difference of about an hour almost!

I tried looking at Compiled Queries and am still figuring it out.
For various reasons, we cant do a database join and retrieve the child values

Here is the code:

```
//listOfDetails is another collection
List<SomeDetails> myDetails = null;
foreach (CustomerDetails myItem in customerDetails)
{

    var myList = from ss in listOfDetails
                 where ss.CustomerNumber == myItem.CustomerNum
                 && ss.ID == myItem.ID
                 select ss;
     myDetails = (List<SomeDetails>)(myList.ToList());
     myItem.SomeDetails = myDetails;
}
```

Comment: Same number of items on both servers ? Comparable hardware ? How long does it take on your local Win7 (an hour might be 800% or 1%, we don't know).

Comment: yes .. the no of records are the same. It takes around 2 minutes to process this loop on Win 7 but around 70 minutes on the server!

Comment: @hangar18: Such a big difference is not really plausible.

Comment: I agree... and thats why we are looking at different possibilities. One among them was this query

Answer (score 7):

I would do this differently:

```
var lookup = listOfDetails.ToLookup(x => new { x.CustomerNumber, x.ID });
foreach(var item in customerDetails)
{
    var key = new { CustomerNumber = item.CustomerNum, item.ID };
    item.SomeDetails = lookup[key].ToList();
}
```

The big benefit of this code is that it only has to loop through the `listOfDetails` once to build the lookup - which is nothing more than a hash map. After that we just get the values using the key, which is very fast as that is what hash maps are built for.

Comment: It boosted the performance well. We got 20 seconds cut down from 27 seconds execution time. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you have the difference in performance, but you should be able to make that code perform better.

```
//listOfDetails is another collection
List<SomeDetails> myDetails = ...;
detailsGrouped = myDetails.ToLookup(x => new { x.CustomerNumber, x.ID });
foreach (CustomerDetails myItem in customerDetails)
{ 
    var myList = detailsGrouped[new { CustomerNumber = myItem.CustomerNum, myItem.ID }];
    myItem.SomeDetails = myList.ToList();
}
```

The idea here is to avoid the repeated looping on `myDetails`, and build a hash based lookup instead. Once that is built, it is very cheap to do a lookup.

Comment: Thanks. i will try with this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

The inner ToList() is forcing an evaluation on each loop, which has got to hurt. The SelectMany might let you avoid the ToList, something like this :

```
var details = customerDetails.Select( item => listOfDetails
    .Where( detail => detail.CustomerNumber == item.CustomerNum)
    .Where( detail => detail.ID == item.ID)
    .SelectMany( i => i as SomeDetails )
);
```

If you first get all the SomeDetails and then assign them to the items, it might speed up. Or it might not. You should really profile to see where the time is being taken.

Comment: This is still O(N^2) instead of O(n)

Comment: Yes, but it will not necessarily need to do all of the operations. My point is that by doing the ToList() every time we are losing the potential benefits of lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd probably benefit from a join here, so:

```
var mods = customerDetails
    .Join(
        listOfDetails, 
        x => Tuple.Create(x.ID, x.CustomerNum), 
        x => Tuple.Create(x.ID, x.CustomerNumber),
        (a, b) => new {custDet = a, listDet = b})
    .GroupBy(x => x.custDet)
    .Select(g => new{custDet = g.Key,items = g.Select(x => x.listDet).ToList()});

foreach(var mod in mods)
{
    mod.custDet.SomeDetails = mod.items;
}
```

<strike>I didn't compile this code...</strike>

With a join the matching of items from one list against another is done by building a hashtable-like collection (`Lookup`) of the second list in O(n) time. Then it's a matter of iterating the first list and pulling items from the `Lookup`. As pulling data from a hashtable is O(1), the iterate/match phase also only takes O(n), as does the subsequent GroupBy. So in all the operation should take ~O(3n) which is equivalent to O(n), where n is the length of the longer list.